# EditText addTextChangedListener not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two EditText input, when text changes after a calculation i have to display result on a textView in same activity. addTextChangedListener is not working for me

```
Activity.java code:
width.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if(!s.equals("") ) {
                TextView perimeterdetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perimeterdetails);
                perimeterdetails.setText(s);
            }
        }
    });
```

XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/width"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/perimeterdetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: What is the problem? try by  perimeterdetails.setText(s+"");

Comment: Not getting any result on TextView, even after trying perimeterdetails.setText(s+"");

Comment: The Code of Above works for me....

Answer (score 1):

change your code as below
Define this in `onCreate`

```
TextView perimeterdetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perimeterdetails);
```

and compare your string as below in onTextChanged

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString())) {
                perimeterdetails.setText(s);
            }
```

Comment: try to clean and build it again, or move it to afterTextChanged

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are define your text view in `onTextChanged`

cut this line `TextView perimeterdetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perimeterdetails);`

befor addTextChangedListener

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  TextView perimeterdetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perimeterdetails);

    width.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if(!s.equals("") ) {

                perimeterdetails.setText(s);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Change the condition :

### if(!s.equals("")){}

to

### if(s.length()!=0){}

Answer (score 0):

do not findViewById inside on Textchanged. Do it before adding the textchangelistener. in the onTextChange
use

```
 if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
perimeterdetails.setText(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
TextView perimeterdetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perimeterdetails);
        width.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {
                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    if(s.length() <= 0) {

                        perimeterdetails.setText(s);
                    }
                }
```

});